# Internet Address Lookup Shows Connected Even If Wifi is Off in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the code below in Flutter to check Internet connection. It used to work with Flutter 1 but now does not with Flutter 2. It is showing that the Android Simulator is connected to the internet whether I am online or not. Would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction. I also tried the [Connectivity Flutter Package](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) with the same result.

```
import 'dart:io';
...
try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    print('connected');
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
  print('not connected');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a network problem with my router. All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? I think with this code will listen to internet connection on a real-time

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();

  subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    // Got a new connectivity status!
  })
}

// Be sure to cancel subscription after you are done
@override
dispose() {
  super.dispose();

  subscription.cancel();
}
```

Comment: I wish to check for the connection at a particular time instead of listening for one. I thought restarting my computer fixed the issue but it seems to be intermittent.